# GeoServer - Specify coordinate precision in GetFeature call

Tags: geoserver, geojson

I am requesting some features as GeoJSON from GeoServer. Can I specify the coordinate precision in my request? I am getting 8 decimals and really only need 3. I'd like to reduce the amount of data in the response and this could be a nice solution. My feature request looks like below.

https://myserverurl.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=myLayerName&CQL_Filter=aVariable=%27a%20value%27&outputFormat=json&srsName=EPSG:4326

Comment: At least it is not a feature that is defined in the WFS standard https://docs.ogc.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html. The purpose of the WFS is to deliver native data without processing it (despite re-projecting to other coordinate system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the number of decimal places in output on the global settings page. See the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#number-of-decimals) for more details.